# How to do a join in hive with a subquery?

Tags: hive, subquery

Im using hive 1.2.1 and I'm running into some problems when trying to join using a subquery.

My main table is applications and I'm trying to join it to table credits, based on account and dates. The date condition is giving me troubles when I try to get just one row (the credit has to be after the application, and it can only be one to avoid dupes in the join). I'm using the following code:

```
SELECT          COUNT(1)
FROM            applications apps
LEFT JOIN       credits c
            ON c.python_id = 
            (
                    SELECT          python_id
                    FROM            credits cr
                    WHERE           cr.ind in ('NP','0P')
                    AND             cr.acct_nbr = apps.acct_nbr 
                    AND             cr.date >= apps.date
                    ORDER BY        cr.date DESC
                    LIMIT 1
            )
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Code: 40000, SQL State: 42000]  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 8:24 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'python_id' 'FROM' in expression specification
```

Could you please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with your query is

```
> hive does not support sub query with equals clause, you can write sub query only for IN, NOT IN, EXISTS and NOT EXISTS clause.
> You cannot have a sub query which returns more than one row.
```

Please look into - [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Subqueries+in+SELECT][1]

There is issue with you logic as well.

My understanding is You are trying to get count from main table wit left join and there is no filter condition defined on outer query to say what records you want.

So the count will always be equal to number of records in main table (applications), If you can provide sample data with expected input and output, we can help you with the query.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should join based on act_nbr and use the date as a filter in the where clause.

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)
FROM    applications apps
JOIN    credits c
ON      c.acct_nbr = apps.acct_nbr
WHERE   c.ind in ('NP','0P')
AND     c.date >= apps.date
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks, however that would not get the applications that didn't join

Comment: Do a left join.

Comment: Hive does not allow left join with inequality conditions

Comment: Also, if I change it to a select *, it will only give me the first row. I need the first row of the credits, hence the subquery. Thanks